# The view chilegaleria.views.AgregarTienda_View didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm getting this error while using django 1.10.6:

> ValueError at /AgregarTienda The view
>   chilegaleria.views.AgregarTienda_View didn't return an HttpResponse
>   object. It returned None instead.

This is my view

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from chilegaleria.forms import AgregarTiendaForm
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'chilegaleria/index.html')
def AgregarTienda_View(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AgregarTiendaForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('chilegaleria:index')
    else:
            form = AgregarTiendaForm
            return render(request, 'chilegaleria/AgregarTienda.html', {'form':form})
```

Also when I add class Meta:
                    model = DatosTienda
to my forms.py file I get this error:

> > C:\chilegalerias>manage.py check Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\chilegalerias\manage.py", line 22, in 
> >         execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\core\management__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
> >         utility.execute()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\core\management__init__.py", line 359, in execute
> >         self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py",
> >     line 294, in run_from_argv
> >         self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py",
> >     line 345, in execute
> >         output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\commands\check.py",
> >     line 68, in handle
> >         fail_level=getattr(checks, options['fail_level']),   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py",
> >     line 374, in check
> >         include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py",
> >     line 361, in _run_checks
> >         return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\core\checks\registry.py",
> >     line 81, in run_checks
> >         new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\core\checks\urls.py",
> >     line 14, in check_url_config
> >         return check_resolver(resolver)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\core\checks\urls.py",
> >     line 24, in check_resolver
> >         for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\utils\functional.py",
> >     line 35, in **get**
> >         res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\urls\resolvers.py",
> >     line 313, in url_patterns
> >         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)   File
> >     "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\utils\functional.py",
> >     line 35, in **get**
> >         res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\urls\resolvers.py",
> >     line 306, in urlconf_module
> >         return import_module(self.urlconf_name)   File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
> >         **import**(name)   File "C:\chilegalerias\chilegalerias\urls.py", line 21, in 
> >         url(r'^', include ('chilegaleria.urls')),   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\conf\urls__init__.py",
> >     line 50, in include
> >         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)   File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
> >         **import**(name)   File "C:\chilegalerias\chilegaleria\urls.py", line 3, in 
> >         from chilegaleria.views import index, AgregarTienda_View   File "C:\chilegalerias\chilegaleria\views.py", line 3, in 
> >         from chilegaleria.forms import AgregarTiendaForm   File "C:\chilegalerias\chilegaleria\forms.py", line 4, in 
> >         class AgregarTiendaForm(forms.ModelForm):   File "C:\chilegalerias\chilegaleria\forms.py", line 7, in AgregarTiendaForm
> >         class Meta:   File "C:\chilegalerias\chilegaleria\forms.py", line 8, in Meta
> >         Model = DatosTienda NameError: name 'DatosTienda' is not defined

This is my forms.py file:

```
from django import forms
from chilegaleria.models import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
class AgregarTiendaForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = DatosTienda
        fields = [
        'nombre',
        'estado',
        'ciudad',
        'comuna',
        'direccion',
        ]
        labels = {
        'nombre': 'Nombre de la Tienda',
        'estado': 'Region',
        'ciudad': 'Ciudad',
        'comuna': 'Comuna',
        'direccion': 'Direccion',
        }
        widgets = {
        'nombre': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'estado': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'ciudad': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'comuna': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'direccion': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> File "C:\chilegalerias\chilegaleria\forms.py", line 8, in Meta Model = DatosTienda NameError: name 'DatosTienda' is not defined

Your log stack says that you must import the model DatosTienda in the file chilegaleria\forms.py

Also check your view, because if you get a GET request, your form is not being defined, so you will get a referenced before assignment an error.

Comment: I fixed it i had indentation errors and also i didn't imported my model

Comment: Good to know! Then you should accept this answer as a correct one. Also try checking out PEP8 for cleaner code.